# PostgreSQL: How to Pass a Rowset to a Function

Tags: postgresql, postgraphile

I'm using Postgraphile, which has you create functions that take row sets as arguments.  For instance, I have a function that takes a `system_versions` row set as a parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.system_versions_edition_versions(
    system_version system_versions,
    system_title character varying DEFAULT NULL::character varying
 )
 RETURNS SETOF edition_versions
 LANGUAGE sql
 STABLE STRICT SECURITY DEFINER
 AS $function$

        SELECT ev.*
        FROM public.edition_versions ev
        INNER JOIN public.editions e ON ev.edition_id  = e.id
        INNER JOIN public.systems s ON e.system_id  = s.id
        INNER JOIN public.system_versions sv ON s.id  = sv.system_id
        WHERE sv.id = system_version.id
        AND (
          system_title IS NULL
          OR
          sv.title = system_title
        )
  ;
  $function$
;
```

Normally these functions are called by Postgraphile, but I need to call this one manually for testing ... and I can't figure out how to provide the parameter.

When I try:

```
SELECT public.system_versions_edition_versions(public.system_versions);
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "public"
LINE 1: select public.system_versions_edition_versions(public.system...
```

But when I try to SELECT the table ...

```
SELECT public.system_versions_edition_versions(SELECT * FROM public.
system_versions);
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 1: select public.system_versions_edition_versions(select * from...
```

When I have a function with a "row set" parameter, can anyone explain how I provide that parameter?

Comment: Looks like you need a view, not a function

Comment: "*Postgraphile, which has you create functions that take row sets as arguments*" - I don't remember that. Can you link the respective part of the docs, please?

Comment: As per the answer, it looks like I was incorrectly calling it a "row set"  when it was actually a row.  Sorry, my PostgreSQL terminology is not the best.

Comment: Note that the

```sql
INNER JOIN public.system_versions sv ON s.id  = sv.system_id
        WHERE sv.id = system_version.id
```

is unnecessary; you can just use `system_version` directly instead of `sv` - there's no need to look up the record from the table when you already have it passed as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `system_version` argument type is row rather than rowset. Otherwise `sv.id = system_version.id` would cause an error. Since `public.system_versions` is a table then `system_versions` is its row type, like `system_versions%rowtype` in PL/pgSQL.
You can call it using a [scalar subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES) like this:

```sql
SELECT public.system_versions_edition_versions(
 (
  SELECT t
  FROM public.system_versions t
  -- WHERE <your logic here>
  LIMIT 1 -- a scalar subquery must return a single row
 )
);
```

or

```sql
select public.system_versions_edition_versions(t)
from public.system_versions t
-- where <your logic here>;
```

You may also consider using a [lateral join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL).